Calculate mean/variance of sums of randomly chosen numbers from an array
Let's say there's an array containing float numbers, and it's size is n. Now m numbers will be chosen out of this array, and these m numbers' sum will generate a new number. So all these possible combinations of such m numbers' sum will form a new array, and I need to calculate mean/variance of this new array.
Selecting 10 numbers out of 100 to form such array and then compute variance would be almost impossible, let alone working on bigger original arrays.
I've actually tried my luck with chatgpt, and it was only able to derive correct equation when choosing 2 numbers out of original array, and looks like it's not just simply changing some parameters to make it work when m is bigger than 2 since chatgpt kept giving wrong answers.
So what's the equation to calculate mean/variance of the new array without actually generating it? And maybe there're better ways to compute?

Start with the mean. You're choosing k = nCm subsets, and summing the subsets, and finding the mean of the sums. Let the sum of the original array be S.
Each number in the array is in m/n of the sums, because each sum picks out every possible m of the n numbers. There are k sums. So the sum of the sums is k*(m/n)*S. The mean of the sums is (m/n)*S.

@SeanOwen, not sure that's right. It looks like you incorrectly calculates the mean of the sums. I think you claim that the mean is $(m/n) \cdot S$, where $S$ is the total sum of the original array, but this introduces an extra $1/n$ factor that is incorrect. I think the correct mean is $m \cdot \mu$, where $\mu = S / n$ is the mean of the original array. This result follows from the linearity of expectation and reflects that each element contributes equally to the sums, scaling directly by $m$, not by $(m/n$).

You gave the same answer I did? You write m*(S/n), but that's (m/n)*S. S is the sum, not mean, of the original array.

@SeanOwen Hmmm. I think the difference lies in interpretation and clarity. While $S$ represents the sum of the original array, the correct formula for the mean of the sums explicitly scales by $m$ without dividing by $n$ twice. My formula $m \cdot (S / n)$ uses $\mu = S / n$ , leading to $m \cdot \mu$. Your formula $(m / n) \cdot S$ introduces ambiguity because it appears to divide by $n$ unnecessarily. Both expressions seem equivalent, but my phrasing avoids confusion by working directly with the mean $\mu$ of the original array, which better reflects the expectation-based reasoning.

I certainly like your writeup, but I do not understand why you say (a/b)c and a(c/b) just 'seem' equivalent. They plainly are the same. I take your point about the importance of clarity, but your offered explanation is just "linearity of expectation", and that is ultimately correct, but I do not see how that is more direct or clear for the likely level of the questioner. Probably wasn't worth the exchange here, but, not worth continuing IMHO

Given:

An array of $n$ floating-point numbers, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$.
All combinations of $m$ elements are considered, and the sum of each subset forms a new array.

If I have understood the question properly, then goal is to compute the mean and variance of this new array of sums without generating all combinations.

1. Mean of the Sums
Let:

$\mu$ denote the mean of the original array.
$\sigma^2$ denote the variance of the original array.

The mean of the sums of all $m$-element subsets is:
$$
\text{Mean of sums} = m \cdot \mu
$$
This follows from the linearity of expectation: each element is equally likely to appear in any subset of size $m$.

2. Variance of the Sums
The variance of the sums of all $m$-element subsets, assuming simple random sampling without replacement, is:
$$
\text{Variance of sums} = m \cdot \sigma^2 \cdot \frac{n - m}{n - 1}
$$
Here:

$m \cdot \sigma^2$ scales the variance to account for the sum of $m$ elements.
$\frac{n - m}{n - 1}$ adjusts for the dependence induced by sampling without replacement.


Python Implementation
import numpy as np

def mean_variance_of_combinations(arr, m):
    """
    Compute the mean and variance of sums of all combinations of m elements
    from the given array.

    Parameters:
        arr (np.ndarray): Array of numbers.
        m (int): Size of each subset.

    Returns:
        tuple: (mean of sums, variance of sums)
    """
    n = len(arr)
    if m > n:
        raise ValueError("m cannot be larger than n")

    mean_original = np.mean(arr)
    variance_original = np.var(arr, ddof=1)  # Sample variance

    mean_sums = m * mean_original
    variance_sums = m * variance_original * (n - m) / (n - 1)

    return mean_sums, variance_sums

# Usage:
arr = np.random.rand(100) 
m = 10   
mean_sums, variance_sums = mean_variance_of_combinations(arr, m)
print("Mean of sums:", mean_sums)
print("Variance of sums:", variance_sums)

Computing all combinations explicitly is computationally impractical for large $n$ and $m$ due to the exponential growth of combinations:
$$
\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m! \cdot (n - m)!}
$$
This approach avoids explicit enumeration by using the properties of expectation and variance.

Edge Cases:

When $m = 1$, $\text{Variance of sums} = \sigma^2$.

When $m = n$, $\text{Variance of sums} = 0$ (since all sums are identical).


Note that the derivations assume simple random sampling without replacement. Results may not hold under other sampling schemes.
